# Graph with uneven intervals on y-axis

Tags: r, plot

I have two vectors to plot. in.down is a function of qu. 
The in.down y-axis need uneven intervals.
The vectors:

```
options(digits=15)

in.down <-                                                                                                                                            
c(seq(0.1,0.9,0.1),0.99,0.999,0.9999,0.999999,0.9999999,0.99999999,
0.999999999,0.9999999999,0.99999999999,0.9999999999999)

qu<-
c(3750,4114,4430,4745,5087,5482,5977,6672,7902,
12559,17677,22237,27652,28841,29480,29813,29985,30072,30138)
```

Now i want that the first sequence (0.1-0.9) of the in.down vector is one interval. After that every further value of the in.down vector is one interval(one tick). The first 8 values of the qu-vector have to lie in the first interval.

I have tried this code, but this don't work:

```
yticks <- c(seq(0, 0.9, 0.9),c(0.99, 0.999999999999))
plot(in.down~qu, ylim=c(0, 0.999999999999))
axis(2, at=yticks, labels=yticks)
```

Comment: What is not right about the plot? Do you want everything after 0.9 to be spaced evenly? It will be tough to render so many ticks in an aesthetically pleasing way otherwise.

Comment: yes it's very important for my researches to show the values higher than 0.9 individual because the distribution has than another shape.